# HashMap changing its values after saving and reading it back from a file

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

I am very confused about my Hashmaps behaviour...

```
HashMap<String, String> wordPairs = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
String[] lines = {"hello", "frühen", "random"};
char[] letters = new char[lines[1].length-2]

for (int i=1; i<lines[1].length-1; i++) {
  letters[i-1] = lines[1].charAt[i];
}

Array.sort(letters);

String str = "";

for (int i=0; i<letters.length; i++) {
  str += letters[i];
}

str = String.valueOf(lines[1].charAt(0)) + 
String.valueOf(lines[i].charAt(lines[1].length()-1)) + str;
wordPairs.put(str, lines[1]);
```

This Codeblock reads a String, from a Stringarray called lines, and saves it as a Value together with its corresponding Key into the Hashmap. The Key consists of the same letters, but in a different order. When I try to print out "str" it gives me the correct str i want, which works also if I try to print the already put Value corresponding to the Key.

The saving process looks like this:

```
ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new 
File("Wordpairs.wordp")));

output.writeObject(wordPairs);

output.close();
```

Now for the confusing part: When I now read it backlike this...:

```
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new 
FileInputStream("Wordpairs.wordp"));
HashMap<String, String> wordPairs = (HashMap<String, String>)input.readObject();
input.close();
```

...and work with it as follows:

```
String string_temp = "frühen";

System.out.println(string_temp);
System.out.println(wordPairs.get("fnehr" + "\u00b3"));
The first line gives me the real word "frühen".
```

The second should give me exactly the same, as "frühen" was previously stored as the Value corresponding to the String "fnehrü" (I used the Unicode Point because "ü"'s are not read from files correctly and for example create a letter with this codepoint). But instead, the second line gives me "führen".

If anybody knows whats going on, help is really much appreciated...
Also feel free to come up with a different solution of saving and reading back HashMaps, i am not restricted to only ObjectIn-/OutputStreams!

Comment: Have you tried to print out `wordPairs` just before saving in the same way you did it after loading? With which result?

Comment: I tried to print out the appropriate Value to the key "fnehrü" before loading, and it gave me the correct Value i wanted: "frühen"...

Comment: Character set problem? Can you specify UTF8 anywhere?

Comment: I do not think so, because the ObjectOutputStream and the ObjectInputStream both, at least to my knowlegde, use a charset of their specification and you cannot intervene with that.

Comment: You could look at the file `"Wordpairs.wordp"` in a hex editor to guess if the file was corrupted during saving. Does this phenomenon also show up with other strings (with or without non-Ascii characters)?

Comment: There are grammertical mistakes in your code. Please fix them. Example: check for loops `for(int i=1, i<lines[1].length-1, i++)`

Comment: Are you aware of `String.toCharArray()` and `String(char[])`?  Maybe simplifying your code would make the problem more clear ...

Comment: +Michael Butscher I tested the Algorythm with several texts and they all worked fine, even words with non-Ascii characters. The only occurence of this problem to me is in the shown example

Comment: @StephenC I was aware of this methods, but i didnt use them since i only wanted the letters in the string except for the first and the last one

Comment: OK.  So you need to provide an MCVE.

Comment: @StephenC Isnt it already an MCVE? What can i do to improve it?

Comment: An MVCE is a program that I can copy and paste into a file, compile, execute, and see the problem that you are talking about.  (And then read or debug ... without having to worry that I might have fixed the bug by accident and / or I might have misunderstood the problem you are talking about.)  MVCE stands for Minimal **Compilable** Verifiable Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my Problem myself!

I was reading the words for the HashMap from a prepared WordList. In this List, two Words contained the exact same letters, so they looked the same after sorting them. In that case, i was simply overwriting the HashMaps Values, because they had the same Key. So it wasnt even a fault in this part of the code, which i should check for the next time...

But thank you all for your opinions and suggestions for answering my question!